# What is the value of this determinant? [2]

Tags: matrices, determinant

If $xyz = -1$, what is the value of the determinant 
$$\begin{vmatrix} x & x^2 & x^3+1\\ y & y^2 & y^3+1 \\ z & z^2 & z^3+1 \end{vmatrix}$$

I need a solution without putting random values of x y and z.
PS don't tell to open the determinant

Comment: Putting in random values will not succeed, because the result may depend on $x,y,z$.  When you say "open the determinant" do you mean expanding it out?  Why shouldn't we tell you that.  If you imagine expanding starting with the first column there are only two terms that start with $x$.  The rest of the expansion can be computed by cyclic shift $x \to y \to z$.  It isn't that hard.

Comment: I am a high school student I don't really understand cyclic shift

Comment: It just means taking the terms and replacing $x$ with $y$, $y$ with $z$, and $z$ with $x$.  The pattern of the matrix makes it clear that will give the four terms that come from the expansion with $y$ and $z$  The term from the main diagonal is $xy^2(z^3+1)$.  The downward term starting with $y$ is then $yz^2(x^3+1)$

Answer (score 3):

$\det\begin{pmatrix} x & x^2 & x^3+1 \\ y & y^2& y^3+1 \\ z & z^2 &z^3+1\end{pmatrix}$

$=\det\begin{pmatrix} x & x^2 & x^3  \\ y & y^2& y^3  \\ z & z^2 &z^3 \end{pmatrix}+\det\begin{pmatrix} x & x^2 &  1 \\ y & y^2&  1 \\ z & z^2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

$=xyz\cdot \det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x  & x^2  \\ 1 & y & y^2 \\ 1 & z  &z^3 \end{pmatrix}+\det\begin{pmatrix} x & x^2 &  1 \\ y & y^2&  1 \\ z & z^2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Now $\det\begin{pmatrix} x & x^2 &  1 \\ y & y^2&  1 \\ z & z^2 & 1\end{pmatrix}=-\det\begin{pmatrix} x &1& x^2  \\ y &1 & y^2 \\ z &1 & z^2 \end{pmatrix}=\det\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x  & x^2  \\ 1 & y & y^2 \\ 1 & z  &z^2 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: What rule did you use in the first step when you splitted the matrix?

Comment: @FareedAF, See Property$\#5$ of https://www.toppr.com/guides/maths/determinants/properties-of-determinants/

Comment: @FareedAF,  $#6$ of https://byjus.com/jee/properties-of-determinants/

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Thanks